# PuppeteerSharp not loading video

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to play video in my puppeteer browser, but once the browser app execute click to play, the video show some error and can not play.
Is the site protection or am I doing something wrong?
If I try other website the click executer normally so what should I do?

**my code:**

```
using puppe_ua;
using PuppeteerSharp;
using PuppeteerSharp.Extra;
using PuppeteerSharp.Extra.Evasions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace pupe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GlobalData.UserAgents = UserAgents.UserAgentData;
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string _userAgent  = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36";
            await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,

                Args = new string[4]
                {
                    "--disable-gpu",
                    "--enable-automation",
                    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                    "--enable-automation"

                }
            });



            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.SetUserAgentAsync("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-A102U Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/74.0.3729.136 Mobile Safari/537.36 Instagram 155.0.0.37.107 Android (28/9; 320dpi; 720x1468; samsung; SM-A102U; a10e; exynos7885; en_US; 239490550)");
           // await page.SetUserAgentAsync(UserAgents.UserAgentData.ToArray);
            await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions
            {
                Width = 720,
                Height = 1468
            });

            await page.GoToAsync("https://live.shopee.com.my/p/share?from=live&session=1231359&viewer=115#copy_link");
            var allResultsSelector = ".bNwffg";
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(allResultsSelector);
            await page.ClickAsync(allResultsSelector);
            //await page.Mouse.ClickAsync(100, 100);


            //("https://bot.sannysoft.com/");
            //wait page.GoToAsync("https://antoinevastel.com/bots"); //https://bot.sannysoft.com/
            //await page.ScreenshotAsync("screens/test.png", new ScreenshotOptions { Type = ScreenshotType.Png });

            //MessageBox.Show("screen done!");
        }

    }
}

public class PuppeteerExtraPluginStealth : PuppeteerExtraPlugin
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> EvasionPluginTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>
        {
            { "navigator.languages", typeof(NavigatorLanguagesEvasionPlugin) },
            { "navigator.plugins", typeof(NavigatorPluginsEvasionPlugin) },
            { "window.outerdimensions", typeof(WindowOuterDimensionsEvasionPlugin) }
        };

    public override string Name => "stealth";

    public override IPluginOptions Defaults
    {
        get
        {
            HashSet<string> availableEvasions = new HashSet<string>
                {
                    //"chrome.runtime",
                    //"console.debug",
                    "navigator.languages",
                    "navigator.permissions",
                    "navigator.webdriver",
                    "navigator.plugins",
                    "window.outerdimensions",
                    "webgl.vendor",
                    //"user-agent"
                };

            return new Options
            {
                AvailableEvasions = availableEvasions,
                EnabledEvasions = new HashSet<string>(availableEvasions)
            };
        }
    }

    public override ISet<Type> Dependencies => new HashSet<Type>(((Options)Opts).EnabledEvasions.Select(x => EvasionPluginTypes[x]));

    public HashSet<string> AvailableEvasions => ((Options)Defaults).AvailableEvasions;

    public HashSet<string> EnabledEvasions
    {
        get => ((Options)Opts).EnabledEvasions;
        set => ((Options)Opts).EnabledEvasions = value;
    }

    public class Options : IPluginOptions
    {
        public HashSet<string> AvailableEvasions { get; set; }
        public HashSet<string> EnabledEvasions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to play video in my puppeteer browser, but once the browser app execute click to play, the video show some error and can not play.
Is the site protection or am I doing something wrong?
If I try other website the click executer normally so what should I do?

Comment: I have this issue too, did you resolve this?

Comment: @MarkRedman yes I did fixed full code is however paid, if you want let me know because I paid developer too

Comment: I fixed this by referencing the path to Chrome (not the built in Chromium) I think this is an issue with codecs, licensing etc? but would only work if I referenced the installed version of Chrome.